# Removing an element from an array when a dropdown item is unselected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have this script that runs when a user selects an element in a dropdown list:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var seSelection = [];

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".dropdown-menu input").click(function() {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $(this).closest("#seButton").data();

            if (this.checked) {
                seSelection.push(this.value);
            }          
        });

        console.log("se equals " + seSelection);
    });
</script>

<button id ="seButton" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
    Options<span class="caret"></span>
</button>

<ul class="dropdown-menu noclose">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ex3_1" name="ex3" value="A" checked="">
        <label for="ex3_1">Option 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ex3_2" name="ex3" value="B">
        <label for="ex3_2">Option 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ex3_3" name="ex3" value="C">
        <label for="ex3_3">Option 3</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap `noclose`, so `dropdown-menu` stays open until I click out of it.  This is designed to allow a user to select multiple options. So as I select various options, my console looks like this, as the script fires on each click:

`se equals` 
`se equals A` 
`se equals A,B` 
`se equals A,B,C`

This is great - and it's functioning properly, but in the same dropdown, if I deselect C after I have selected it, it doesn't REMOVE `c` as a value from the array `seSelection`.

I'm not sure how to write the code that does the inverse of what my script's code above does since I can't find any `unclick(function)` or `unpush(this.value)` that exists in jQuery.

How do I write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On unchecking you can remove the item from the array just like this http://jsfiddle.net/93zL0ae9/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var seSelection = [];
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".dropdown-menu input").click(function() {
    var value = $(this).val();
        $(this).closest("#seButton").data();
        if (this.checked) {
           seSelection.push(this.value);
        }
        else
        {
           var index = seSelection.indexOf(this.value);
           if(index>=0)
           {
              seSelection.splice(index,1);
           }
        } 
    console.log("se equals " + seSelection);         
  });

});
</script>


<button id ="seButton" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">Options<span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu noclose">
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="ex3_1" name="ex3" value="A" checked="">
      <label for="ex3_1">Option 1</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="ex3_2" name="ex3" value="B">
      <label for="ex3_2">Option 2</label>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="checkbox" id="ex3_3" name="ex3" value="C">
      <label for="ex3_3">Option 3</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect.  I had to enclose your `if(index>=0)` statement with a `{` and a `}`, but apart from that, this works perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's because the instance is still being saved in your global variable, seSelection.  I bet you if you unselect and then re-select an option it would show up twice.

It depends what your requirements are, but you probably instead want to generate that array of results from scratch after each click.  You can do this by moving your `var seSelection = [];` line within the anonymous callback function, as well as that `console.log` statement.

Comment: Yes, if I unselect and reselect it appears twice.  I'm in the process of writing another part to this `if` statement to include `$.inArray` so I can stop that from happening, but I still don't understand how to make something REMOVE from the array when it's deselected in the dropdown menu.... edit: oh... I get what you're saying.... let me try that :)